# Determine max and min for the function: f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2x-4y

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

My problem is defined to determining the max and min for the function: 
 $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2x-4y $$ within the domain: 
$$ x^2+y^2\leq9$$

And I've been able to locate the minimum which is found within the domain. I am having trouble locating the maximum on the rim (saddle?).

The way I've started is to substitute x, y with $3\cos(t)$ and $3\sin(t)$ respectively and I get:

$$9-6\cos(t)-12\sin(t) $$
$$f'(t)=\sin(t)-2\cos(t)$$ 
$$\tan(t)=2 \\ t=\arctan(2)+\pi*n\ $$

But here my Trigonometry fails me, how do i resubstitute $t$ into the original function?

$$ x=3\cos(\arctan(2)+\pi*n) \\ y=3\sin(\arctan(2)+\pi*n)$$

Is this correct, if so how do I continue?

Comment: Hint: if you complete the squares in $f$ you will get a simple form which you should be able to recognise and work with.

Comment: $\cos t = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t}} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. So $(\cos t, \sin t) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$ or  $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, this is easy. $f(x,y) = (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2-5 = d(x,y)^2 -5$, where $d(x,y)$ is the distance from $(x,y)$ to the point ($1,2)$.

So you only have to maximise the distance from $(1,2)$ to the circle $r^2=3$, which occurs at the point diametrically opposite $(1,2)$, i.e. $(-\frac{3}{\sqrt 5},-\frac{6}{\sqrt 5})$.

Comment: I like your answer

Answer (score 0):

If $\tan(t) = 2$, then $|\sin(t)| = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $|\cos(t)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: While this does take a step towards the Answer to the original Question posed, and is relevant to where the OP was able to leave the solution, it is incomplete and likely includes possible solutions that need to be discarded.

Comment: It's easy though. $\tan t > 0$ means $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are both positive or both negative

Answer (score 0):

On the rim, the problem is equivalent to: Find the extreme points on $$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 2x - 4y$$ with the constraint $$ g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 = 9$$

This can be solved using Larange multipliers

$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\nabla f(x, y) = \lambda \nabla g (x, y) \\
g(x, y) = 9 
\end{matrix} \right. 
\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} 
2x - 2 = \lambda 2x \\
2y - 4 = \lambda 2y \\
x^2 + y^2 = 9 
\end{matrix} \right. 
\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\lambda = \frac{x-1}{x} \\
\lambda = \frac{y-2}{y} \\
x^2 + y^2 = 9 
\end{matrix} \right. \\
\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\frac{x-1}{x} = \frac{y-2}{y} \\
x^2 + y^2 = 9 
\end{matrix} \right. 
\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} 
y = 2x \\
x^2 + y^2 = 9 
\end{matrix} \right. 
\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} 
y = 2x \\
x^2 + 4x^2 = 9 
\end{matrix} \right. 
\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} 
y = 2x \\
x = \pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{matrix} \right.
\\ \Rightarrow (x, y) = \left( \frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{6}{\sqrt{5}} \right), 
\left( -\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}, -\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}} \right)
$$